# Miccrosoft Graph acces token failed to fetch (Javascript)

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am currently writing an application for the Office365, I need to get the user's access token and everything seems to be fine, however...: My code throws an Error but my network debugger shows that it had a good response... 
I do not understand why I get a error, even though the response is OK.

**Code**

```js
async getUserAccesToken(code) {
    var resource = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantDomain}/oauth2/v2.0/token`;
    var tokenRequest = {
        client_id: clientId,
        scope: 'offline_access user.read',
        code: code,
        redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/acces',
        grant_type: 'authorization_code',
        client_secret: clientSecreta
    }

    return await this.getEncodedPostResponse(resource, tokenRequest);
}

async getEncodedPostResponse(resource, postBody) {
    var encodedPostBody = Object.keys(postBody).map((key) => encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(postBody[key])).join('&');
    debugger;
    return await fetch(resource, {
            method: "POST",
            body: encodedPostBody,
            headers: new Headers({
                'Accept': 'application/json; charset=utf-8;',
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            debugger;
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(jsonResponse => jsonResponse);
}
```

**The Error (1/2)**
[image: ErrorDetails]

**The Error (2/2)**
[image]

**The success response in my Chrome debugger**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

- You're getting an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. Your server needs to define it's rules for cross-domain calls in the header of it's HTTP responses. The Mozilla docs contain an excellent article on this topic: [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).
- You're confusing the Access Token with the Authorization Code. You're `getUserAccesToken` is actually requesting an Auth Code. The Access Token is returned by issuing a `POST` back to the endpoint to convert your Auth Code to an Access Token.
- It looks like you're attempting to `POST` from the client side. This call belongs server-side. Your first call requests the Auth Code by `login.microsoftonline.com`. Once the user authenticates, `microsoftonline.com` will send the user to the `redirect_uri`. When you're server receives this request, it needs to issue the `POST` to obtain the Access Token for the user.

I have an article that walks through how the Authorization Code flow works with the v2 Endpoint that you might find helpful: [Microsoft v2 Endpoint Primer](http://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-primer/).

Comment: Thank you, I solved the problem by requesting the **authorization_code** through Node JS